# store permanently data in RouteData.Values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm going to store some keys with values in **RouteData.Values** and pass data between controllers and views,

```
RouteData.Values.Add("MyKey", "MyValue");
```

I will use value in **_Layout** to show value in all views, 
but it seems all keys will be removed when you go to other controller.

Is there anyway to store some keys permanently in **RouteData.Value**, and prevent from remove it?

If not, Where can I store some Data like this and access it from View?

I Don't want to use **ViewBag** or **ViewData** because I do not access them from **IRouteConstraint**

Comment: You could use .NET Session if you like

Comment: You can use a baseController class for these jobs. All controllers use this baseController, and you can define all common objects in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **baseController** class for these jobs. All controllers use this **baseController**, and you can define all common objects in this.

Like this:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        RouteData.Values.Add("MyKey", "MyValue");

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and other controllers

```
public class HomeController : BaseController 
{
    // get route data values 
}
```

Comment: Great solution; can you say what's the benefit of this method than Sessions ?? Thank you

Comment: You can initialize other common data in it. This logic is the same with masterpages for controllers. Also, you can manage your user data, localization data, exceptions, messages for views and etc... I mean more manageble controllers...

Comment: Check [THIS](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/NET-best-practice-samples-4e9b92a4#content) and [THIS](https://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Presentation/Nop.Web.Framework/Controllers/BaseController.cs)